# How to use a custom font in Xcode's attributes builder

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Can someone outline the procedure to use custom fonts in Xcode's attributes builder. I was hoping to use the .storybuild file (not using code) to create a UILabel with the custom font "Delicious". I downloaded the .otf file, added it to the Font Book, copied the font file into the project folder in Xcode, added "Fonts provided by application" with the font name to the -file.plist. But I still cannot see the font in the attributes builder drop down font list. Do I need to do anything else?

PS: I am using Xcode 4.5.

Comment: Having this issue too. I'm looking to do quick UI prototypes & don't want to get into code; everything I find seems to indicate that using IB / Storyboards to set fonts is not possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe you can get custom fonts to show in the dropdown in interface builder. IB only shows fonts available on the device OS you are targeting. If you want to use custom fonts, you will have to set them in some code.

http://kgriff.posterous.com/45359635